# Intro at the beginning of the app

Tags: ios, xcode

On some apps, they have a little intro, that you can slide through different view controllers, that talk about it. For example: Evernote, etc.  What's the name of this? And any good tutorial on how to do it?

Answer (score 14):

No,There is no any ready made controller not available for introduction.You need to implement `UIScrollView` and create your custom view and put into that `scrollview`.

Following is the list of the different github demo projects for intro screen.

1. [Surfboard](https://github.com/MosheBerman/Surfboard)
2. [EAIntroView](https://github.com/ealeksandrov/EAIntroView)
3. [iPhone-IntroductionTutorial](https://github.com/MatthewYork/iPhone-IntroductionTutorial)
4. [GHWalkThrough](https://github.com/GnosisHub/GHWalkThrough)
5. [AOTutorial](https://github.com/Appsido/AOTutorial)
6. [MYBlurIntroductionView](https://github.com/MatthewYork/MYBlurIntroductionView)
7. [ICETutorial](https://github.com/icepat/ICETutorial)
8. [ABCIntroView](https://github.com/AdamBCo/ABCIntroView)
9. [EKWelcomeView](https://github.com/EvgenyKarkan/EKWelcomeView)

May this help lot,

Happy coding.

Comment: two more fancy github projects here:

https://github.com/Ramotion/paper-onboarding

https://github.com/ephread/Instructions

Answer (score 4):

You can also use UIPageViewController.

**1. Create an instance of UIPageViewController**

```
    self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll 
                                                              navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal 
                                                                            options:nil];
    self.pageViewController.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

**2. Implement its UIPageViewControllerDataSource protocol**

```
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
    ....
    - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController 
          viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
    {

       NSUInteger index = [(PageContentViewController *)viewController pageIndex]; // get any kind of index of the view controller to know its position
        // here I subclass UIViewController to hold the index

        if (index == 0) {
            return nil;
        }  

       // get the previous view controller
       return self.pages[--index]; // container of all your pages
    }


    - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
         // do the same as above but get the next view controller or nil if index >= [self.pages count]
     }

     - (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
        // how many items do we have
        return [self.pages count];
     }

     - (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
        // The selected item reflected in the page indicator.
        return 0;
     }
```

**3. Create your pages.**

```
     self.pages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     for (NSUInteger i=0; i<10; i++) { // 10 pages
         PageContentViewController *page = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController1"]; // you can also do it programmatically
         // subclass of UIViewController just to hold its page index and for unified style purpose
         page.pageIndex = i;
         [self.pages addObject:page];
     }
```

**4. Display pages**

```
     NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.pages[0]];
     [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

     [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
     [self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
     [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

**5. Dismiss**

```
     [self.pageViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
     [self.pageViewController removeFromParentViewController];
```

*Want to add some fancy animations when page view controller is shown?*

```
     CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
     transition.duration = 0.4;
     transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
     transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
     transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
     [self.pageViewController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
```